How to create custom component type in MJML GrapesJS
I have started working on GrapesJS with MJML. Before implementing the same in my project, I am learning the concept and working of GrapesJS. Almost all basic things are clear to me but now I want to create a custom component type where I want a button with icon. I know I can achieve the same by using default Button component and adding images in it. But still I want a single component where icon will be an google material icon.
To accomplish it, I want to give a dropdown with component where user will select the material icon name and icon will render accordingly.
I have tried a lot but still concept to add new component type with few settings is not cleared to me. For me grapes documentation is not sufficient to clear concept of adding and using new component type.
How can I add new component type for button with icon and how can I use it as a block in GrapesJS?
